# Return first unique value in a column with MySQL once

Tags: mysql

I have the following table named stuff:

```
Serial  Color
1       Red 
2       Red
3       Green
4       Blue
5       Green
6       Green
7       Orange
```

I run  a simple select query:

```
SELECT * FROM stuff ORDER BY Serial
```

This simply returns all entries ordered by the Serial. But what I actually need, is for the query to only return the first unique occurrence of each Color while maintaining the same order.

The result set I need returned:

```
1       Red 
3       Green
4       Blue
7       Orange
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the `color`s and take the lowest `serial` for each group. You can also order by that

```
select min(serial), color
from your_table
group by color
order by min(serial)
```